# Retrieve user input from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the customer record from my database thats is determined by the id.
What I already have is a return where the id = 42. What I want to do is make it where the record returned is based on the id number that the user inputs on a previous page, which is $customerid. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
 }
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parameter passed to the PHP via GET or POST using $_GET["param_name"] and $_POST["param_name"] respectively.

So if your page is called using

```
http://path/to/page.php?id=99
```

You can get 99 in $_GET["id"]

Similar for POST.

Answer (score 0):

Not having seen your form, I am assuming that you will `POST` the data.
Here is my suggestion for how to handle the data:

```
$id=isset($_POST['id'])&&is_numeric($_POST['id'])?$_POST['id']:false;

if ($id) {

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = $id;");
  if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
   }
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

  echo $row[0]; // 42
  echo $row[1]; // the email value

} else {
  echo "ERROR: No ID specified.";
}
```

Also, consider using PDO as mysql_* statements are depreciated. At the least, investigate how to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

search.php

```
<form action="show_record.php" method="post">
<input name="customer_id" />
</form>
```

show_record.php

```
<?php
    // use $_REQUEST to get a parameter from POST OU GET request method
    $id = isset($_REQUEST["customer_id"]) ? $_REQUEST["customer_id"] : 0; 

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(); // prevent sql inject

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '$id'");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
     }
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    echo $row[0]; // 42
    echo $row[1]; // the email value

    ?>
```

So, you can request the page show_record.php from POST or GET, anyway the answer will be the same.

Via GET:

localhost/show_record.php?customer_id=42